# AppFabric Error @ objCache.Get(key)

Tags: appfabric

I am able to put/add 70MB of data to AppFabric successfully. But I am getting following error when I try to retrieve the same thru `_cache.Get(key)` method.

1. Please let me know what's wrong.
2. Let me know if its good this huge data

**Error**

> "ErrorCode:SubStatus:The connection was terminated,
>   possibly due to server or network problems or serialized Object size
>   is greater than MaxBufferSize on server. Result of the request is
>   unknown."

**Stack Trace**

```
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody)
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalGet(String key, DataCacheItemVersion& version, String region)   
at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.Get(String key)
```

**Web Config at client**

```xml
<dataCacheClient requestTimeout="150000" channelOpenTimeout="20000" maxConnectionsToServer="1">
    <localCache isEnabled="false" sync="TimeoutBased" ttlValue="300" objectCount="10000"/>
    <clientNotification pollInterval="300" maxQueueLength="10000"/>
    <hosts><host name="MachineName" cachePort="22233"/></hosts>
    <securityProperties mode="None" protectionLevel="None" />
    <transportProperties connectionBufferSize="131072" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxOutputDelay="2" channelInitializationTimeout="60000" receiveTimeout="2147483647"/> 
</dataCacheClient>
```

**Configuration at Server**

```xml
<transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider an alternate solution to put a 70MB object. AppFabric is meant for very frequently accessed volatile data, ideally below 256kB (looking at their [benchmark results](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=212272), which were available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg186017%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)).

Note: The benchmark results link seems to be broken at the moment.